# Check if an index exists in another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Is there a way to check if an index exists in another database?

AFAIK, the usual ways (`sys.indexes` and `INDEXPROPERTY`) only run in the context of the *current* database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check the `sys.indexes` from another DB, same as you would with any other table.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyOtherDb.sys.indexes
WHERE name = 'MyIndex'
```